# Angular Express Routing 500 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I am using angular and express for an app, but I can't get the client routing to render a partial... My app structure is:

```
-project
  -public
     -javascripts
        -app.js ( angular app module )
        -controllers
            -LoginCtrl.js
  -server.js  
  -views
     -index.ejs
     -partials
        -login.ejs
```

In my server.js file, I handle the routing which loads my index file:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

// This callback from router produces the error
app.get('/partials/:name', function (req, res) {
        var name = req.params.name;
        res.render('partials/' + name);
    });
```

The client side routing is handled:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).
    config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            $routeProvider
                .when("/login", { templateUrl: "partials/login.ejs", controller: "LoginCtrl" })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/login" });
        }
    ]);
```

My index.ejs file has all the necessary includes, are the includes not ordered properly?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

  <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/services.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/directives.js"></script>

  <script src="javascripts/controllers/LoginCtrl.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is the app not configured properly?

```
app.configure(function() { 

    // set up our express application
    app.use(express.logger('dev')); // log every request to the console
    app.use(express.cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
    app.use(express.bodyParser()); // get information from html forms

    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    app.use(express.methodOverride());    
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
```

I have tried with and without the html5Mode set, but neither seem to work. I get this error both ways:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/partials/login.ejs 500 (Internal Server Error) angular.js:8495
(anonymous function) angular.js:8495
sendReq angular.js:8291
$http.serverRequest angular.js:8025
wrappedCallback angular.js:11498
wrappedCallback angular.js:11498
(anonymous function) angular.js:11584
Scope.$eval angular.js:12608
Scope.$digest angular.js:12420
Scope.$apply angular.js:12712
(anonymous function) angular.js:1419
invoke angular.js:3918
doBootstrap angular.js:1417
bootstrap angular.js:1431
angularInit angular.js:1344
(anonymous function) angular.js:21817
trigger angular.js:2550
(anonymous function) angular.js:2823
forEach angular.js:325
eventHandler
```

Comment: What error is your server code throwing?

Comment: no, this is the only error when i type http://localhost/5000 into the browser

Comment: Looks like you are following a tutorial. if so, please share it with us.

Comment: im not, i was going off of this seed https://github.com/btford/angular-express-seed